# I am trying to get this glass to show the colored mesh behind it, it wont work, i have version 2.90

Tags: glass

[image: Blender]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0gvV.jpg)

Am trying to render this glass in blender, it wont show what,s behind it. its not a background, it is a colored mesh

Comment: Is this in EEVEE? If so, you may need to change the blending mode in the material settinsg to be able to see the stuff behind the glass.